# 2 column div layout, right column fixed width, always centred

Tags: html, css, layout, multiple-columns

I'm trying to place some content within a table cell but it needs to meet the following specifications.

The content I'm adding is:

`x *`

Where `x` is any number (i.e a variable length) and `*` is a picture of a star, which will be a fixed length of let's say `y`px. I want this content to appear centred in the table cell, with `x` always being `z` pixels to the left of `*`. For example's sake, let's say the `*` is 16px wide, and `z` is 2px (i.e a 2px spacing between `x` and the star picture.

I've tried a simple 2 column layout where I float the `x` to the left, float the `*` to the right, which works but does not center the two columns, instead `x` sticks to the left of the table cell, and `*` sticks to the right of it.

Any help appreciated :) . I can use JS if need be, but I'd prefer a HTML/CSS solution of course.

Comment: Any sample code ? if you want to center mutiple elements on the same line, you can give them `display: inline` and set `text-align: center` on the parent

Comment: do you mean this? http://jsbin.com/puwoyavibe/1/   code: http://jsbin.com/puwoyavibe/1/watch

Comment: When you say length do you mean width?

Comment: @NoahMLively Not exactly. I have a `td` and want to place something similar to `<div>1</div><div>*</div>` inside it, where the second `div` is always 16px and 2px to the right of the first, but the two divs together are centred in the td. The second `div` will actually have no content apart from a background `img`.

Comment: @hungerstar Yes, so the first div may have the number `0`, or the number `9999` etc, i.e its width will vary.

Comment: well you need a div wrapper for your divs (i used the cell as the container) and if they dont have a width they will not center and since your numbers are dynamic you can use jQuery. here sorry so sloppily written im about to fall asleep http://jsbin.com/gesajeyiya/1/watch

Answer (score 0):

here just in case the jsBin expires i will put the code in an answer. once again excuse my sloppy code, im literally about to fall asleep

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
   td { width:300px; height:300px;border:1px solid;position:relative;}
   td img {width:100%;max-width:16px;padding-left:2px}
  .num { float:left}
  .wrapper { margin:0 auto;}
</style>
<script>
   $(function(){
      width = $('.num').width() + 18;
      $('.wrapper').css('width',width.toString() + 'px');
    });
</script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class='num'>1234</div>
        <img src="http://www.wpclipart.com/signs_symbol/icons_oversized/male_user_icon.png">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsbin.com/gesajeyiya/1/watch

Comment: This works, but unfortunately I cannot use an img element and need to stick with my `div` and a background `img` file.

Comment: i chose an img element because of its ease of use when responsive plus transparent pngs dont show as backgrounds in older internet explorer browsers. i cant see why you would have to use a div with a css background. but do what you do. at least mark it as correct.

Comment: I cannot mark it as correct as it does not answer my question. My specification is for it to use a div element with a background image, and your answer does not provide this.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you will only be displaying numbers of 0 to 9999 then you do not need a script

http://jsbin.com/vagulejaqi/1/watch?html,css,output

```
  <table id="your-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class='cell-inner-wrapper'>
            <div class='my-numbers'>
              9999
            </div>
            <img src="https://www.novell.com/documentation/groupwisemobility2/gwmob2_guide_admin/graphics/icon_user_n.png">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class='cell-inner-wrapper'>
            <div class='my-numbers'>
              1
           </div>
           <img src="https://www.novell.com/documentation/groupwisemobility2/gwmob2_guide_admin/graphics/icon_user_n.png">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


#your-table {
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:12px;
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#your-table td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width:50%;
}
.cell-inner-wrapper {
  //12px * 4 + 16px + 2px
  max-width: 66px;
  text-align:center;
}
#your-table td img{
  padding-left: 2px;
  display:inline;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.my-numbers {
  max-width:48px;
  display:inline;
  line-height:4.5em;
}
```